# How Can I use IF&ELSE in Controller - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel

This is a simple classic jackpot system. 
My preference is to randomly select in the database if the selected user has null value.
if the winner has any value but not null (user_id), do not randomly select and win that user.
If winner_id has null value, choose random. but if you have a predefined winner_id (not null (example: winner_id = 152)), gain 152 users.

ClassicController.php:

```
public function getWinners()
{
    $us = $this->usersGame();

    $lastBet = Bet::where('game_id', $this->game->id)->orderBy('to', 'desc')->first();
    $winTicket = round($this->game->rand_number * $lastBet->to);
    if($winTicket == 0) {
        $winTicket = 1;
    }

    $winningBet = Bet::where('game_id', $this->game->id)->where('from', '<=', $winTicket)->where('to', '>=', $winTicket)->first();
    $userWin = User::find($winningBet->user_id);

    $this->redis->del('last.ticket.' . $this->game->id);

    $this->game->winner_id = $winningBet->user_id;
    $this->game->status = 3;
    $this->game->finished_at = Carbon::now();
    $this->game->won_items = json_encode($this->sendItems($this->game->bets, $userWin));
    $this->game->chance = $this->userChance($userWin, $this->game);
    $this->game->save();

    foreach ($us as $user) {
        $user->itemsCount = $this->userItem($user, $this->game);
        $user->itemPrice = $this->userPrice($user, $this->game);
        $user->percent = $this->userChance($user, $this->game);
    }

    $winner = [
        'randNumber' => $this->game->rand_number,
        'avatar' => $userWin->avatar,
        'GameSecret' => $this->game->secret,
        'name' => $userWin->username,
        'TicketWin' => $winTicket
    ];

    $returnValue = [
        'differenceDelay' => 0,
        'endtimestamp' => Carbon::now()->getTimestamp(),
        'prize' => $this->game->price,
        'userList' => [
            'users' => $us
        ],
        'winner' => $winner
    ];

    return response()->json($returnValue);
}
```

Datebase SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `winner_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `items` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` double(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `started_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `finished_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `won_items` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status_prize` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `chance` double(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `secret` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rand_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```